# Does ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib's FastZip supports setting compression level?

Tags: compression, sharpziplib, fastzip

It seems fast, what could be its compression level? Can it be changed?

I'm using FastZip so I can show a progressbar.  I tried Peter Bromberg's sample code first, setting the compression level is possible, but don't have a sample code for progress event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this
http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/6835/19472.aspx

from JohnReilly:

> Hi, FastZip and ZipFile dont currently
>   support setting the compression level.
>   They both use maximum compression.
>   Cheers, -jr-

Comment: I have a pull request pending that will add it to the repo. https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/pull/129

Comment: It appears that FastZip supports setting the compression level now through the FastZip.CompressionLevel property. https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/help/api/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.FastZip.html